# Determine where my traffic is coming from?

Tags: site-growth

My community has grown in fits and starts over the years. There are long lulls of a stable user base, then we get an influx of users over the course of 3-5 days. Some of those users end up sticking around and the stable user base grows a bit and enters another lull. The process repeats several weeks or months later.

The problem is, I have no idea where these influxes of users are coming from. I'd love to reach out to the areas of the internet they come from, but I don't know where to reach.

We've tried talking to the various waves of users, but no one really remembers how they ended up here in the first place. Once and a while someone can point to a Facebook post or a Twitter message where we are mentioned, but so far none of those have been posted around new waves.

How can I track inbound traffic *and* user retention so that we can plan our out reaches?

Answer (score 6):

Four things come to mind regarding *inbound traffic origin*:

1. Configure [Google alerts](https://www.google.com/alerts) on the name and URL of your community. That will not give you *direct* links, but at least you'll notice when and where you are mentioned.
2. Your site analytics should be able to give you a list of [referers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), i.e. the previous URLs where your users came from. This may be the most direct indicator.
   E.g. to do this in Google Analytics [read these articles](https://www.google.nl/search?q=show+refererers+in+google+analytics)
3. If your website analytics software does not already do this for you: Convert the IP addresses of your users to country location. Very rough, but again, at least it's *some* info.
4. Several software packages are able to count/list [pingbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback) from the referer information. If you e.g. use Wordpress, [this supports them](https://en.support.wordpress.com/comments/pingbacks/).

As far as *user retention* is concerned, again, web analytics software usually can give you the percentage of repeat visitors. The precision depends on what the software tracks - it can be very crude like only IP address (lumping all visitors behind a router together as one), but they often use better tracking (cookies or [browser fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint)) to distinguish actual individuals.

Comment: I thought about the referrers, but it doesn't seem that reliable to me. Or it's not a path to exactly where the community was mentioned but instead just the generic top level domain (facebook.com. That isn't helpful). I will dig some more into the analytic platform we do have. Maybe there is more to it than I realized. It seems most of your suggestions revolve around that. Thank you.